# Spring Boot -> using logback-spring.xml, rollover is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.2,and I have logback-spring.xml as below -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
  <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
 <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root> 
</configuration>
```

My pom.xml has -

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
     </dependency>
```

My application.properties file is as -

```
logging.file=xyz.log
```

But the log files are not rolling back when it reaches 10 MB. Tried using below also, still log files are not rolling back.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
  <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
<appender name="ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/log/xyz.log</file>       
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>/log/xyz%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>      
    </rollingPolicy>
<triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
      <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
    <encoder>

        <pattern>%relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root> 
</configuration>
```

Any help/ suggestion is appreciated !!!

Answer (score 1):

Spring-boot rolls log files at the 10MB point automatically.
As long as you have the logging file property configured you don’t need to do anything else.
The logback dependencies are included with the starter pom, also you shouldnt be using log4j and logback at the same time.
Remove the logging xml config, remove all the logging dependencies from your pom and it will just work.
For completeness, if you wanted to use a size other than 10MB, then you would need to add a logback config.
The simplest way to do this is to copy the existing base config and implement your own file-appender rules.

Example `logback-spring.xml`, using a 20MB rolling size:
**You don’t need to use this if you just want the default 10MB.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- Import default spring logback configuration -->
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />

    <!-- Define your file-appender -->
    <appender name="FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%i</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>20MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```